# Using RabbitMQ at ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

Clients use iOS app + RabbitMQ to send messages on the server.

Sellers use ASP.NET MVC web site.

How can I use RabbitMQ for ASP.NET MVC to get messages from server?

If I subscribe to RabbitMQ channel as consumer inside controller, this doesn't work because controller returns View and EventHanlder doesn't fire.

Comment: If you need to deliver messages to clients in real-time - you need persistent connection from client to asp.net application, like websockets or SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subscribing and recieving message from rabbitmq in global.asax or startup or program (if this selfhost) or another place which can be initialized on start. ASP.NET mvc in this case doesn't matter.