# Send message to cshtml page via RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, signalr

I have:

- ASP.NET MVC site for sellers.
- A separate server which uses RabbitMQ to send messages.

How can I get these messages at cshtml page? I can subscribe to RabbitMQ at server side of ASP.NET MVC and use SignalR to send message to client, but it seems ugly.

Comment: Similar question. SignalR or WebSockets is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909462/using-rabbitmq-at-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Asking the same vague question twice isn't going to produce more answers. Fix your question. You don't send anything to any page. Your *application* listens for messages. Your *controller* checks for messages before rendering a view. If you want to send **notifications** to the **browser** you need a notification mechanism like WebSockets, long polling, infinite frames etc. SignalR is a library that uses all of them, depending on the browser's capabilities

Comment: OK. But how can I wait messages from RabbitMQ in ASP.NET MVC ?
Controllers returns View for the client and I can't handle messages

Comment: You must read about SignalR. Using which you can call client side function as you get response from MQ using Hub class. An easy to follow tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

Comment: SignalR works well. How can I wait messages at ChatHub class?